# Get the order id from the current user orders In WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

Here is the situation. I have a woocommerce site used as a marketplace. I'm selling games on it, for some the purchaser receive a steam key. For that I'm working on a key attribution system, so by going on a page, the key will be attributes to the user.

For that, I want to check all orders made by the current user (the on log-in and on the page) and check the game he has bought.

I find some very usefull information here: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details)

However, I don't manage to get all orders the current user. I have first think to make a SQL request, but I don't find the link on the database between order and user.

Have you any lead?

Comment: Always ask questions having some code and the issue you have in the code here.

Comment: Here is the point. I have the code to do after, and it's working correctly. I just don't manage to have that part.
But I understand, thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Updated** *Added Compatibility with WooCommerce 3+ (January 2018)*

Here is the code that you will need to get all customer orders and to go through each items of each customer order:

```
## ==> Define HERE the statuses of that orders 
$order_statuses = array('wc-on-hold', 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed');

## ==> Define HERE the customer ID
$customer_user_id = get_current_user_id(); // current user ID here for example

// Getting current customer orders
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value' => $customer_user_id,
    'post_status' => $order_statuses,
    'numberposts' => -1
) );


// Loop through each customer WC_Order objects
foreach($customer_orders as $order ){

    // Order ID (added WooCommerce 3+ compatibility)
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    // Iterating through current orders items
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){

        // The corresponding product ID (Added Compatibility with WC 3+) 
        $product_id = method_exists( $item, 'get_product_id' ) ? $item->get_product_id() : $item['product_id'];

        // Order Item data (unprotected on Woocommerce 3)
        if( method_exists( $item, 'get_data' ) ) {
             $item_data = $item->get_data();
             $subtotal = $item_data['subtotal'];
        } else {
             $subtotal = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal', true );
        }

        // TEST: Some output
        echo '<p>Subtotal: '.$subtotal.'</p><br>';

        // Get a specific meta data
        $item_color = method_exists( $item, 'get_meta' ) ? $item->get_meta('pa_color') : wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'pa_color', true );

        // TEST: Some output
        echo '<p>Color: '.$item_color.'</p><br>';
    }
}
```

This code is tested and works

---

Related:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Accessing Order Items protected data in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597491/accessing-order-items-protected-data-in-woocommerce-3/43619678#43619678)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I'm facing an issue with that line: foreach($customer_order->get_item() as $item_id => $item_values)

The error is: Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Post::get_item()

Comment: I fix that by replacing with: foreach(wc_get_order($order_id)->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values). 

It seems to be working, I just need to have other information such as getting the product name. I should get it on my own. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it's a bug while synchronized my account on iPhone. I haven't used Stackoverflow since yesterday. I realized that the word Solved has been removed of the title too. Answer is marked again as accepting ;)