# Accessing Order Items protected data in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce, orders

I am trying to get the line items of an order.

I'm doing this:

```
$order = new WC_Order(147);
foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {
    print_r('<pre>----');
    print_r($lineItem);
    print_r('----</pre>');
}
```

I can see all the data I need but the array shows this:

```
[meta_data:protected] => Array
```

How can I access this array to get the values?

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to access it with: $lineItem->get_meta_data()

Answer (score 31):

> Since WooCommerce 3.0+ for Order items there is new Object class [**`WC_Order_Item_Product`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html).
>   **Now Order items properties can't be accessed directly as before**

So if you look at your output raw data you will see that each line item is now an object, and you will be able to access that protected data using exclusively:

1. [**`WC_Order_Item_Product`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html) **getters methods** (or to change it with the setters methods)…
2. [**`WC_Order_Item`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order_Item.html#238-284) **`get_formatted_meta_data( '', true )`** method to access all meta data. It gives an array of accessible objects. See [**`WC_Data`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) method **`get_meta()`** to access each meta data.
3. [**`WC_Data`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) getters methods to unprotect this data and access it through arrays using methods:

   - **`get_data()`** *(this method is the very useful)*
   - **`get_meta()`** *(this method is the most useful)*
   - `get_data_keys()`
   - `get_meta_data()` *(**does not unprotect the data**, use `get_formatted_meta_data()`)*
4. [**`wc_get_order_item_meta()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order_item_meta.html) dedicated function.

The [**`WC_Order_Item_Product`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html) **getters methods**:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order(147);

// Iterating through each order item
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    echo $item->get_type().'<br>'; // The order item type
    echo $item->get_product_id().'<br>'; // The Product ID
    echo $item->get_variation_id().'<br>'; // The variation ID
    echo $item->get_quantity().'<br>'; // Line item quantity
    echo $item->get_subtotal().'<br>'; // Line item subtotal
    echo $item->get_total().'<br>'; // Line item total

    // The associated product object (which properties can't be accessed directly too)
    echo '<pre>'; print_r( $item->get_product() ); echo '</pre>'; 

    // ... and so on ...

    ## Testing raw output (protected)
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r($item); echo '</pre>';
}
```

The [**`wc_get_order_item_meta()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order_item_meta.html) function. Here you can go in **`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`** table and output any data for an item ID using the corresponding **`meta_key`** (for `line_item` data type item ID):

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order(147);

// Iterating through each order item
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    echo wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', true). '<br>'; // Product ID
    echo wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_variation_id', true). '<br>'; // Variation ID
    echo wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_qty', true). '<br>'; // quantity
    echo wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal', true). '<br>'; // Line subtotal

    // ... and so on ...

    ## Testing raw output (protected data)
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r($item); echo '</pre>';
}
```

The [**`WC_Data`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) method `get_data()` method (to unprotect the data in an array):

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order(147);

// Iterating through each order item
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    // Get the most useful Item product data in an accessible array
    $item_data = $item->get_data();

    echo $item_data['id'].'<br>'; // The order item ID
    echo $item_data['order_id'].'<br>'; // The order ID
    echo $item_data['product_id'].'<br>'; // The Product ID
    echo $item_data['variation_id'].'<br>'; // The Variation ID
    echo $item_data['name'].'<br>'; // The Product title (name)
    echo $item_data['quantity'].'<br>'; // Line item quantity
    echo $item_data['subtotal'].'<br>'; // Line item subtotal
    echo $item_data['total'].'<br>'; // Line item total

    // ... and so on ...
```

The [**`WC_Data`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) method `get_meta()` method (to access each property by its meta key):

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order(147);

// Iterating through each order item
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    echo $item->get_meta('_product_id').'<br>'; // The Product ID
    echo $item->get_meta('_variation_id').'<br>'; // The Variation ID
    echo $item->get_meta('_qty').'<br>'; // Line item quantity
    echo $item->get_meta('_line_subtotal').'<br>'; // Line item subtotal
    echo $item->get_meta('_line_subtotal_tax').'<br>'; // Line item subtotal tax
    echo $item->get_meta('_line_total').'<br>'; // Line item total
    echo $item->get_meta('_line_tax').'<br>'; // Line item total tax

    // Product attributes for variation
    echo $item->get_meta('pa_color').'<br>'; // Color
    echo $item->get_meta('pa_size').'<br>'; // Color

    // Custom item meta gata
    echo $item->get_meta('custom_meta_key').'<br>'; // custom meta key visible


    // ... and so on ...
```

Related: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: Thank you. I wish this was more clear in the documentation.

Comment: The `wc_get_order_item_meta()` worked for me. The way I used it successfully looked like this: `echo wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Booking Date', true);`

Answer (score 4):

To get the data of `[meta_data:protected] => Array` You need to use another method.

Just use this `$item_obj->get_meta_data();`

A more detailed way to get them, iterate them twice as follows:

```
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_obj) {

         $kua = $item_obj->get_meta_data();

         foreach ($kua as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
               echo $key2.'->'.$value2.'<br>';
            }
        }
  }
```

Collection of the methods is located [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html)

Comment: in wocommerce 3+ nothing print